# What files do I need to code sign on Windows Electron app?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, electron, code-signing, authenticode

I want to sign a Windows Electron app. Do I only need to sign the installer that will be downloaded by the user or do I also need to sign the `.exe` (or `.dll` files) before they will be packaged by the installer?